# What in google's DCM api will give me the returned fields' datatypes?

Tags: google-api

I have a dcm api request that gives me a bunch of [metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdNOx.png) and [dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL6Ae.png) for an organization, and I want to type hint those fields to sqlalchemy types when I store them in a pandas dataframe rather than relying on pandas guessing (dfa:clicks would be Integer, dfa:ad would be String, etc).

Is there an api call I can make that will return me the datatypes of the fields?